# Trending Feeds Machine Learning Model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am a beginner in machine learning. I want to build a model for finding trending feeds like Instagram. 
Please suggest which model is recommended for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to choose these modeling frameworks like Modeling choices, Data freshness trading, and Novelty effect, Experimentation (A/B) Small Effects, Impact, and Scientific Method, Normalization, Iteration Speed — Offline Analysis, Value Modeling, and Parting Thoughts.
Moreover, since you are a beginner, you can get expert guidance for machine learning related questions at `Mayazbridge.com`. Mayazbridge is the software training institution in kukatpally giving postgraduate courses with career guidance. Hope my answer helps you.